# Can one see which .profiles are sourced at a bash prompt?

Tags: bash

So in any new unix variant I come to I'm always hesitating on where to look for the .profile for bash. This can even be true for weird instances of bash running on my own machine.

Instead of searching through the internet each time, is there a way of seeing which .profiles are currently loaded in bash?

Something like

```
$ source --list-sourced
```

Comment: Except $HOME/.profile and friends ?

Comment: Exactly. On my mac that would be ~/.bash_profile but that profile does not include my entire path so there must be some more general profiles being sourced before that. I'd like a neat way of seeing them all.

Comment: /etc/profile and /etc/profile.d/ and the files sourced from your bashrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you're the one to invoke the shell, you could simply do a `bash -v`; the output of mine starts with

```
$> bash -v
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi
# /etc/bashrc

# System wide functions and aliases
# Environment stuff goes in /etc/profile

# It's NOT a good idea to change this file unless you know what you
# are doing. It's much better to create a custom.sh shell script in
# /etc/profile.d/ to make custom changes to your environment, as this
# will prevent the need for merging in future updates.
....
```

which gives you a pretty good start on what is happening, and where to look.

If that is not feasible, you'll have to examine the paths that bash specifies it uses (from `man bash`):

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads  and 
>   executes  commands
>          from  the  file  /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and
>   ~/.profile, in that
>          order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may  be  used  when 
>   the  shell  is
>          started to inhibit this behavior.

Comment: Ah, the bash -v flag didn't do anything in my case but reading the man page was indeed a good way of finding out. Thanks!